# игнорировать метод с помощью атрибута

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Могу ли я как-то в зависсимости от передаваемого значения игнорировать или выполнить метод. Например:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CanAddAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public int Count { get; set; }        

    public CanAddAttribute(int count)
    {
         if (count < 3) // то все ок, и выполнить метод после атрибута
         else // не выполнять метод
    }
}
```

Ну и после

```
[CanAdd]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // что-то делается
}
```

PS специально написал у атрибута кривой конструктор, потому что без понятия как так сделать, и вообще возможно ли

UPDATE

`Count` был для примера. На самом деле я собираюсь в конструкторе вызвать функцию, которая сможет проверить нужное мне (написал далее) и возвратить (например `bool`)

Для чего это все надо:

1) Есть программа (сторонняя), которая генерирует(зашифровывает данные) ключ.

2) Ключ считывается с конфига (уже моей программы) ( в нем есть ограничение на использование софта, например максимальное количество пользователей).

3) В некоторых функциях я хотел бы запускать проверку (валидацию, которая бы проверила, можно ли добавить еще пользователя или нет.

4) т к функция постоянно однообразна, я бы хотел реализовать это атрибутом ( в данный момент это реализовано так: статический метод-расширение, который принимает в качестве аргумента метод (внутри сначала проверяет можно ли, и если да, то выполняет метод) ну и возвращает просто результат-обертку.

Почему взгляд пал на атрибуты: я подобную реализацию встречал на [asp.net 4.6 (атрибут Authorize)](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). если кто то может - объясните где искать принцип его работы.

Comment: а зачем это необходимо? значение count будет известно на этапе компиляции и "зашито" в аттрибут (т.е. не зависеть от какой-то внешней переменной), а в таком случае я думаю можно как-то применить https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, И что же тогда меняется? Вы читали то про этот атрибут?

Comment: @ヒミコ ну например, то что не нужно создавать новый аттрибут и добавлять его поддержку в код, а с помощью #define или опций компилятора вкл/выкл часть кода, я прекрасно понимаю, что нам условие не напишешь `count < 3`, но и надобность кода из вопроса я пока не понимаю (для меня это какой-то костыль)

Comment: Реализовать такое возможно. Через конструктор `[CanAdd(3)]` передаем значение свойству `public int Count { get; set; }`, а затем в методе, кот. будет запускать `TestMethod()` c помощью рефлексии находим атрибут, значение свойства `Count` и выполняем метод или нет. Но! Это нарушение ООП и такую магию внедрять в код большое зло. Не нужна эта хреновина от слова совсем.

Comment: @Bulson спасибо за комент,  "Но! Это нарушение ООП" - полностью с вами согласе. Дополнил вопрос...поглядите, возможно появятся другие мысли

Comment: @ExplodingKitten обновил вопрос, посмотрите, возможно мысли появятся

Comment: И еще, возможно будут предложения кроме атрибута